# JOINS with Many to Many Relationship - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables in a many to many relationship `countries and teams table`. In my country table, there is `president_id`. Now i want to get teams that belong to that president_id using a join query but i am not able to achieve this.

How can i achieve selecting all teams belonging to a particular president?

**PS**: Newbie with laravel

**Country**

```
public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team');
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Team**

```
public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$teams = Team::all()->with('countries')->where('president_id,1)->first();
$getTeams =  $teams->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can get all teams that has countries with some `president_id` like this:

```
$president_id = 1;
$teams = Team::whereHas('countries',function($q)use($president_id){
             $q->where('president_id',$president_id);
         })->get();
```